# How to check a variable is it the Database and print it out?

Tags: sql, perl

I got a list of variables to loop through the database. How can I detect the variable is not in the database? What query should I use? How to print out error message once detected the variable is not in database.

My Code:

```
$variable = $sql->{'variable'};

foreach my $sql (@Records){

**Below statement will select existed variable, what should I change to make it select not existed variable**

$sqlMySQL = "Select LOT from table where LOT like '%$variable%'";

}

**If not exist**{

print("Not exist")

}
```

Expected result:

While the `$variable` loop through the database, if the `$variable` not exist in the database then print out the `$variable` or not exist.

Thanks for viewing, comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it similar to the below.

1. A list of variables - Place those variables in an array (aka a list)
2. What query should I use - One that will only select exactly what you need and store it in the best dataset for traversal (selectall_hashref)
3. While the $variable loop through the database - Would require a `DBI` call for each `$variable`, so instead loop through your array to check for existence in the hash.

**EXAMPLE**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
my $dbh =
  DBI->connect( "dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.db", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD",
    { RaiseError => 1 },
  ) or die $DBI::errstr;
my @vars = ( 25, 30, 40 );
my $hash_ref =
  $dbh->selectall_hashref( q / SELECT LOT FROM table /, q / LOT / );
$dbh->disconnect();

foreach (@vars) {
    if ( exists $hash_ref->{$_} ) {
        print $_ . "\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Does not exist\n";
    }
}
```

Something similar to that will pull all the `LOT` column values for your table into a hash `key` `value` pair that you can then compare against your `array` in a `foreach` loop.